# Store one copy of mail in sent mail when submit a web form

Tags: php, forms, email

I would like to create a sent mail web form to sent email to my customer. Form fields will be as follows-

1. Receiver Email
2. Company Name and
3. Signature

Sender Email: info@example.com

Every time I will send email from info@example.com. I know that when I sent an email from horde, squirrelmail or roundcube, each sent email stored as sent mail items.

Now, my question is-
Can I store my emails in ***Sent Mail*** if I use PHP mail function if I use web form?

Comment: No it won't. This is strictly up to the mail *client* to save a copy in the Sent Mail folder. The default php `mail` function won't do that. You could look into some of the existing imap function to try to replicate that behaviour (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php)

Comment: It's probably just as easy to cc (or bcc) yourself if all you want is to keep a copy for yourself

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, try to actually read the question before firing your guns

Comment: @Ben, I am able to store one copy in inbox. Are there any possibility to store as sent mail items?

Comment: May be my English is not good enough, though the question is not fake or meaning less. I was really hurt. :(

Comment: you should look at `imap_append` (http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-append.php) and use it to save a *copy* of the email, separately from sending it with `mail`